# Include markup in web component content insertion

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

I have started to take a look at web components and the shadow DOM and have setup a simple demo. I have noticed that by setting an insertion point in my `<template></template>` and including it multiple times in the host it will iterate over each occurrence for one reference in the template.

```
    <template>
        <content select="item"></content> <!-- will include multiple instances of item -->
    </template>

    <fancy-list>
        <item>test</item>
        <item>test 2</item>
    </fancy-list>
```

This made me think about simplifying the markup in the host and adding some structure to  almost like it was it's own component.

This is the approach I am currently using:

```
    <template id="fancyList">
        <ul>
            <content select="item"></content>
        </ul>
    </template>


    <fancy-list class="fancyList">
        <item><li><span>test</span></li></item>
        <item><li><span>test 2</span></li></item>
    </fancy-list>
```

This works however I am having to specify the markup of an item inside the host which feels counter intuitive to the entire concept of web components. Does anyone know if something like this would be possible:

```
    <template id="fancyList">
        <ul>
            <content select="item"><li><span></span></li></content>
        </ul>
    </template>


    <fancy-list class="fancyList">
        <item>test</item>
        <item>test 2</item>
    </fancy-list>
```

Ideally I want to move any markup structuring to just the template allowing the `<item>` to be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly done. The only thing left is to use it’s own template for `item`s. Since `item` is not a valid name for a web component, the example below uses `fancy-list-item`:

```
<polymer-element name="fancy-list-item" noscript>
  <template>
    <li><content></content></li> <!-- style as you want -->
  </template>
</polymer-element>
<polymer-element name="fancy-list" noscript>
  <ul>
    <template>
      <content select="fancy-list-item"></content>
    </template>
  </ul>
</polymer-element>


<fancy-list>
  <fancy-list-item>test</fancy-list-item>
  <fancy-list-item>test 2</fancy-list-item>
</fancy-list>
```

Hope it helps.